# Firebase Admob not displaying ads on Real Device in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

My ads shows correctly on emulator, but when i test it on real devices, it doesnt show ads. here is my code below:

=>lib/main.dart;

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

const String testDevice = 'ca-app-pub-366*******150~415*****06';
const String DWWCBannerAdUnit = "ca-app-pub-3666******50/910*****770";
const String DWWCAppId = "ca-app-pub-366*******150~415*****06";

Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: DWWCBannerAdUnit,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: DWWCAppId,);
  createBannerAd()
    ..load()
    ..show();
  runApp(dwwc());
}
```

Comment: I didn't work with admob, but maybe it's because your real device doesn't have a Google account activated

Comment: @GTG which error code you are getting in your console ?

Comment: I myself have heard that if you use a real device and run in the app in 'release' mode the ads might not show up. They should show up after a while, or after you submitted the app to the play store/app store. Although I'm not 100% sure on this as I never had any issues with it myself.

Comment: @OstapFilipenko I appreciate your concern and response to my question. i wish to notify you that after publishing my app on Google Play Store, my ads started displaying correctly. :)

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I appreciate your concern and response to my question. i wish to notify you that after publishing my app on Google Play Store, my ads started displaying correctly. :)

Comment: @TomTruyen I appreciate your concern and response to my question. i wish to notify you that after publishing my app on Google Play Store, my ads started displaying correctly. :)